# jQuery mouseover link to show hidden div not working on hover exactly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement when a div1 is hovered div2 should be visible and options should be clickable. when div1 is mouse out it should not show div2

```
<div class="div1">Hover me</div>
<div class="div2">Clickable items</div>

.div1
{
  width:100px;
  height:30px;
  background:red;
}

.div2
{
  width:100px;
  background:blue;
  display:none;
  padding:10px;
}

$('.div1').hover(function()
{$('.div2').show()});
$('.div2').hover(function() 
  {}, function() {$('.div2').hide()});
```

This solution works partially, After the element is hovered and when the mouse is moved downwards it works fine. but when the mouse is moved upwards it doesnt dissepear sub menu.

here is the pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwWGVq

Comment: because you never mouseover the sub menu

Comment: I have tried this but still i am unable to click on div2 contents when its shown http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rayqLv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jQuery is wrong, see below:

```
$('.div1, .div2').hover(function(){

    $('.div2').show();

}, function(){

    $('.div2').hide();

});
```

Comment: I have tried this but i am unable to click on div 2 when it is shown.

Comment: You leave div1 so it is going to hide if there is any separation btween the sub and the heading.